# is there a way to check if two left-child right-sibling trees are equal?

Tags: c++, class, recursion, tree, operator-overloading

I am currently working on the equality operator overloading for the left child right sibling class, and this function is supposed to check if two trees have the same root, same kids and same sibs(or overall if the two trees are exactly the same)

```
bool CTree::operator==(const CTree &root){
if(this->kids!=nullptr){
return ((kids)==(root.kids));
}
else{
if(this->sibs!=nullptr){
return ((sibs)==(root.sibs));
}
else{
return (data==root.data);
}
}
}
```

This is my current function to check if two left-child right sibling trees are equal; I think this has two problems that I can't find a way to get around it; first, it returns kids==root.kids without checking the sibs, and second this function stops checking the equality of the two trees once kids and sibs points to null. I attempted to write a second function

```
bool CTree::operator==(const CTree &root){
  if(this->kids!=nullptr){
    if (!(kids==root.kids)){
        return false;
      }
  }
  else{
    if(this->sibs!=nullptr){
      if (!(kids==root.sibs)){
          return false;
        }
    }
    else{
      if (!(data==root.data)){
          return false;
        }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

But this also doesn't check the equality of two trees properly. Can someone give me a hint how to proceed? I included part of my header file for reference

```
class CTree {
  friend class CTreeTest;

  char data;     // the value stored in the tree node

  CTree * kids;  // children - pointer to first child of list, maintain order & uniqueness

  CTree * sibs;  // siblings - pointer to rest of children list, maintain order & uniqueness
                 // this should always be null if the object is the root of a tree

  CTree * prev;  // pointer to parent if this is a first child, or left sibling otherwise
                 // this should always be null if the object is the root of a tree}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to tell if we could see the CTree header

Comment: @Jeffrey Sorry I forgot to include it! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: What's a CTree? I've never heard of this data structure before. I'm having trouble grasping the difference between `kids` and `sibs` based on the description.

Comment: Your structure doesn't make sense to me. How does one know how many kids there are? Same question for sibs.

Comment: I wonder that you compare `data == root.data` last. I would do this comparison first to terminate the recursion as early as possible. It doesn't make sense to check all the children of nodes (pair-wise) if the nodes itself are not equal, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I've never heard yet about (the term) left-child-right-sibling-trees (or I already forgot about it). However, I've already seen something like this in action when I used [libXml2](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html).
(Have a look at [`struct _xmlNode`](https://github.com/tenderlove/libxml2/blob/ecb5d5afdc8acceba608524f6e98c361fd2ce0e9/include/libxml/tree.h#L450) to see what I mean.)

So, I explain how I would make the comparison `CTree::operator==()`:

```
    bool operator==(const CTree &cTree) const
    {
```

1. I would compare the `data` first. There is no need to traverse any child or sibling if the root nodes have different data.

```
      if (data != cTree.data) return false; // unequal data -> equality failed
```

2. Next step is to compare the `kids` pointers pair-wise.
   If one of the nodes has children but the other has not the equality comparison can bail out. For this, I simply convert the pointers into `bool`s.

```
      if (!kids != !cTree.kids) return false; // only one has kids -> equality failed
```

3. The same is done for the sibling pointers.

```
      if (!sibs != !cTree.sibs) return false; // only one has sibs -> equality failed
```

4. Now, both or none of the nodes have children. So, for the former case, the first recursion into the children is done. (In the latter case, this step can be skipped.)

```
      // recursion into kids (if there are kids)
      if (kids && *kids != *cTree.kids) return false; // kids exist but are unequal
```

5. In the final step, the recursion has to be done for siblings if there are siblings. Otherwise the nodes (sub-trees) are considered already as equal at this point.
   I use the logical-or which is short-circuit. Hence, if `sibs` has a `nullptr` the right hand side is skipped and `!nullptr` (`== true`) is returned. Otherwise, the return value results in the comparison of siblings.

```
      // recursion into sibs (if there are sibs)
      return !sibs || *sibs == *cTree.sibs; // no sibs or result of sibs equality check
```

6. That's it.

```
    }
```

7. For symmetry (and because it was already used) the counter-part `operator!=()` has to be defined as well. It simply builds upon `operator==()` and AFAIK this is very usual.

```
    bool operator!=(const CTree &cTree) const { return !(*this == cTree); }
```

I made an MCVE to check and demonstrate this. Thereby, I changed the type of `data` from `char` to `std::string` to make it a bit more illustrative:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CTree {
  private:
    std::string data;
    CTree *kids;
    CTree *sibs;
    CTree *prev;
  public:
    CTree(const std::string data = ""):
      data(data), kids(nullptr), sibs(nullptr), prev(nullptr)
    { }

    // adds a child.
    void add(CTree *kid)
    {
      if (kids) {
        kids->prev = kid; kid->sibs = kids; 
      }
      kids = kid; kid->prev = this;
    }

    bool operator==(const CTree &cTree) const
    {
      if (data != cTree.data) return false; // unequal data -> equality failed
      if (!kids != !cTree.kids) return false; // only one has kids -> equality failed
      // recursion into kids (if there are kids)
      if (kids && *kids != *cTree.kids) return false; // kids exist but are unequal
      if (!sibs != !cTree.sibs) return false; // only one has sibs -> equality failed 
      // recursion into sibs (if there are sibs)
      return !sibs || *sibs == *cTree.sibs; // no sibs or result of sibs equality check
    }

    bool operator!=(const CTree &cTree) const { return !(*this == cTree); }
};

CTree* install(bool complete)
{
  CTree *pRoot = new CTree("/");
  CTree *pBin = new CTree("bin/"); pRoot->add(pBin);
  CTree *pUsr = new CTree("usr/"); pRoot->add(pUsr);
  CTree *pBash = new CTree("bash"); pBin->add(pBash);
  CTree *pCsh = new CTree("csh"); pBin->add(pCsh);
  if (complete) {
    CTree *pEtc = new CTree("etc/"); pRoot->add(pEtc);
    CTree *pInitD = new CTree("init.d"); pEtc->add(pInitD);
  }
  return pRoot;
}

int main()
{
  CTree *drv1 = install(false);
  CTree *drv2 = install(false);
  CTree *drv3 = install(true);
  std::cout << "drv1 == drv2? " << (*drv1 == *drv2 ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
  std::cout << "drv1 == drv3? " << (*drv1 == *drv3 ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
  std::cout << "drv2 == drv3? " << (*drv2 == *drv3 ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
drv1 == drv2? yes
drv1 == drv3? no
drv2 == drv3? no
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fc7636191450411)

---

Thinking twice, I realized that the equality `operator==()` can be written even more compact although I neither think it improves readability nor I expect any performance win:

```
    bool operator==(const CTree &cTree) const
    {
      return data == cTree.data // unequal data -> equality failed
        && !kids == !cTree.kids // only one has kids -> equality failed
        && !sibs == !cTree.sibs // only one has sibs -> equality failed
        && (!kids || *kids == *cTree.kids) // no kids or result of kids equality check
        && (!sibs || *sibs == *cTree.sibs); // no sibs or result of sibs equality check
    }
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e82b9295e1826d1)